# Read from file and transfer on a dynamic struct

Tags: c, file, memory-management, struct, binary

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

> Create the files stringhe.h stringhe.c that let you use the following structures and function"

```
struct stringa {
    unsigned char length;
    char *s;
};

struct stringa *read_stringhe_bin(const char *filename, unsigned int *pn);
```

> The structure contains the `length` field that contains the length of the string (possibly 0) and `s` field that points to a zero-terminated string (of length `length`). The function takes as a parameter a file name that is to be opened in read mode untranslated (binary) and a pointer to an `unsigned int` variable in which you will have to enter the number of strings in the file.
>
> The file consists of a sequence of length elements
>   variable in which a byte indicating the length `n` of the string and below there are `n` bytes containing the characters of the string.
>
> The function must return a pointer to a new memory area (dynamically allocated
>   heap) containing all strings read from the file. The number of strings is not known a priori and not limited.
>
> It can be bound by the code. Even the `s` string element must be dynamically allocated heap.

This is my code:

**stringhe.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stringa {
    unsigned char length;
    char *s;
};

#ifndef READ
#define READ
struct stringa *read_stringhe_bin(const char *filename, unsigned int *pn);
#endif // !READ
```

**stringhe.c**

```
#include "stringhe.h"

struct stringa *read_stringhe_bin(const char *filename, unsigned int *pn) {
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(filename, "r+b");
    if (f == NULL) exit(1);

    struct stringa *lista;
    lista = malloc(0);
    lista->s = malloc(0);

    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        char a;

        fseek(f, 1, SEEK_CUR);
        if (fgetc(f) == EOF) break;

        fseek(f, -2, SEEK_CUR);
        fread(&a, 1, 1, f);

        lista = (struct stringa *)realloc (lista, sizeof(struct stringa) * (size_t)(i + 1));
        lista[i].length = a;
        lista[i].s = malloc(sizeof(char) * (size_t)a);

        fread(lista[i].s, 1, (size_t)a, f);
        lista[i].s[a] = '\0';
        (*pn)++;
    }

    fclose(f);

    return lista;
}
```

I passed to the function the following binary files:

```
05 43 69 61 6F 21 00 03 61 62 63 0E 50 72 6F 67
72 61 6D 6D 61 7A 69 6F 6E 65
```

which is translated into:

```
.Ciao!..abc.Prog
rammazione
```

So... my function through debugging seems to work perfectly, however when I upload it to the website of our professor to see if it really works, it says that the `main` (created by the professor, and I can not see) ended incorrectly.
So I doubt that I had done something wrong with the memory allocation or something similar. Could you give me a hand to understand the error and possibly improve this my code to make it more powerful?

Comment: Ouch: the `unsigned char` for length limits strings to 255 characters (perhaps plus 1 for the null byte). But the structure wastes 3 bytes on a 32-bit platform and 7 on a 64-bit platform; it could replace the `unsigned char` with `unsigned long` and not change the space used by the structure while radically increasing the range of string sizes the structure can represent. I realize there's not much you can do about the assignment you're given, but don't be afraid to critique assignments, at least to yourself (you might not be so popular with your tutor — though you could simply ask questions).

Comment: Note that the professor probably runs your program against a read-only copy of a data file (he won't want student's code modifying his data), so the `"r+b"` mode in `fopen()` would fail to open the file, causing your program to fail his test.  It is also worth adding an error message explaining why your code is exiting — written to standard error, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code:

You open the file with `"r+b"` mode.  Update is useless and error prone, just use `"rb"`.

If the file cannot be opened, you might just return `NULL` instead of exiting the program.

```
lista = malloc(0);
lista->s = malloc(0);
```

`malloc(0)` may return `NULL` or the address of an object which you are not supposed to write to.  You should instead do this:

```
lista = NULL;
```

When allocating the space for the string characters:

```
lista[i].s = malloc(sizeof(char) * (size_t)a);
```

You should allocate one extra byte for the terminating `'\0'` that you set after reading the bytes from the file.  Do this:

```
lista[i].s = malloc(a + 1);
```

Seeking to check for end of file is cumbersome and may actually not be supported by the stream.  Just read one byte for the size into an `int`, check for `EOF` and then allocate and read the specified number of bytes for the contents:

```
    int a;

    a = fgetc(f);
    if (a == EOF) break;

    lista = realloc(lista, sizeof(*lista) * (size_t)(i + 1));
    lista[i].length = a;
    lista[i].s = malloc(a + 1);
    lista[i].s[a] = '\0';

    if (fread(lista[i].s, 1, a, f) != a) {
        // file format error, ignore this incomplete string
        break;
    }
```

You should also check for `malloc` and `realloc` potential failure to allocate memory and return `NULL` gracefully.

Finally, the way you return the number of strings allocated is incorrect:

```
(*pn)++;
```

You do not know if `*pn` is `0` upon entry into your function... It might just be uninitialized in `main()`.  Fix this by setting it once at the end of the parsing loop:

```
*pn = i;
```

Also why do you surround your function declaration in `stringe.h` with `#ifndef READ` etc.  What is the purpose of this *protection*?

Comment: I noticed the odd header guards in the header, assuming `READ` is a header guard.  I'd spell out that the header file should use something like: `#ifndef STRINGHE_H_INCLUDED`, `#define STRINGHE_H_INCLUDED` at the top and `#endif /* STRINGHE_H_INCLUDED */` at the bottom (comment optional but recommended), with everything else except comments in between those two groups of lines. Or find a question to x-ref; there are many of them. Also, the header shouldn't include either `<stdio.h>` or `<stdlib.h>` — they're not needed by the structure or function. Headers should be minimally self-contained.

Comment: Header file `stringe.h` could indeed protect the multiple definition of the structure `struct stringa`.  The guard used currently does not protect the right thing and uses a symbol that is not specific enough.

Comment: Incidentally, good job on the rest of the dissection of the code. That was a minor nitpick. I'm not entirely clear what the `fseek(…, +1, …)` is doing; presumably it is checking that there is a byte beyond the length byte, but it seems idiosyncratic to do it that way. I'd just read the length byte (checking for EOF), and then proceed from there. That would avoid the need for the `fseek(…, -2, …)` of course. But you point out that the return values from I/O functions should be checked to ensure that they succeeded. (I'm also puzzled by the 'modern fad' for using `fgetc()` instead of `getc()`.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I'm puzzled too! it seems to come from the fact that `getc()` is frowned upon by some teachers because is implemented as a *macro*... precisely the reason why oldtimers such as you and I would prefer to use `getc()` !

Comment: @chqrlie Nice solution. **If the file cannot be opened...** yeah you're right but i used it just for the debugging. I ruined my life with the fseek function going back and forward because initially I wanted to stop the cycle with the feof function, but I noticed that even after reading all the file, this function signaled me the end of the file after performing also another cycle for, so I decided to marry a step forward with the fseek function to check the eof without another useless cycle.

Comment: @chqrlie **You do not know if * pn is 0 upon entry into your function ...** In fact, that was the problem of my code, that tells me error. Thanks